# Android Listview to show all files/folders in a directory

Tags: android, android-listview

i want to create a list-view in android so that it can take the names of all the files or folders that are in one folder and show these names in listview 
These folders are located on external storage. i have tried many ways but none seems to be useful.
i have searched for many tutorials but i couldn't found anything like that..
Need help .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayList<File> files;

public void getList(String directoryPath) {
    File f = new File(directoryPath);
    File file[] = f.listFiles();
    folders = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
         files.add(file[i]);
    }
}
```

to get names -

```
String name = files.get(position).getName();
```

Comment: You must accept it as answer if it solved your problem@SparrOw

Comment: oh yeah .. sorry i forgot OOps

Comment: @SparrOw yeah, use above code its perfect, have you know how to inflate these in ListView??

Comment: are you there? have you done?

Comment: You can use custom adapter(which will extend BaseAdapter) to inflate them. In "getView" you can get the position.@pratik

Comment: always at your service :) @SparrOw

Comment: Thank u ,,u guys are great .. yeah i think i will do it ... :)

Comment: void is an invalid type for the variable getList.. @Vicky what should i do now?

Comment: @SparrOw I will post custom adapter code. You could use it.

Comment: @SparrOw I can't add the answer, dont know why. Just message me here , when you come, I ahve a code for it.

Comment: @SparrOw I think you have defined the method inside another method. Just move getList() method outside of any method.

Comment: ok .. i have solved this problem

Comment: i need help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511696/how-can-i-use-android-file-explorer-to-move-any-type-of-file